# How can I monitor directories in vala?

Tags: monitoring, inotify, vala

How can I  asynchronously monitor some directories in vala? All I need is for a callback method to be called whenever a file in one of the directories is:

- created
- deleted
- modified

I found [GLib.FileMonitor](http://www.valadoc.org/references/gio-2.0/0.11.5/GLib.FileMonitor.html) but I am unsure how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To monitor a directory, you need to first create a GLib.File from that directory by using one of the GLib.File.new_* static methods. [new_for_path](http://www.valadoc.org/references/gio-2.0/0.11.5/GLib.File.new_for_path.html) is probably what you want.

You then need to create a GLib.FileMonitor for that directory using the [monitor_directory](http://www.valadoc.org/references/gio-2.0/0.11.5/GLib.File.monitor_directory.html) method of the GLib.File object.

You can then connect to the [changed](http://www.valadoc.org/references/gio-2.0/0.11.5/GLib.FileMonitor.changed.html) signal of the GLib.FIleMonitor object.

When you compile, you will need to include `--pkg gio-2.0`.

**Example:**

```
void on_change () {
    print("changed\n");
}

void main () {
    GLib.File usr_share_applications = File.new_for_path(
        "/usr/share/applications"
    );
    GLib.File local_share_applications = File.new_for_commandline_arg(
        GLib.Environment.get_user_data_dir() + "/applications"
    );

    GLib.FileMonitor mon1;
    GLib.FileMonitor mon2;

    try {
        mon1 = usr_share_applications.monitor_directory(
            GLib.FileMonitorFlags.NONE
        );
        mon1.changed.connect(on_change);
        print("Monitoring: "+usr_share_applications.get_path()+"\n");
    } catch (GLib.Error e) {
        print("Error: "+e.message+"\n");
    }
    try {
        mon2 = local_share_applications.monitor_directory(
            GLib.FileMonitorFlags.NONE
        );
        mon2.changed.connect(on_change);
        print("Monitoring: "+local_share_applications.get_path()+"\n");
    } catch (GLib.Error e) {
        print("Error: "+e.message+"\n");
    }

    GLib.MainLoop loop = new GLib.MainLoop();
    loop.run();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Always fallback to the original documentation: http://developer.gnome.org/gio/unstable/GFileMonitor.html

You create a monitor from a GLib.File, then connect to the **changed** signal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a C example using only inotify.  Although it is standalone, it can be modified to work as an idle process (instead of as while(1)) and call a callback (instead of printf)

```
/* inotify us of the file changes in directory */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>

#define EVENT_SIZE  ( sizeof (struct inotify_event) )
#define EVENT_BUF_LEN     ( 1024 * ( EVENT_SIZE + 16 ) )

int main(int argc, char** argv){
int length, i, watch, fd = inotify_init();
char buffer[EVENT_BUF_LEN];

if ( fd < 0 ) perror( "inotify init failed" );

watch = inotify_add_watch( fd, argv[1], /* should check if argv[1] is a dir */
  IN_CREATE | IN_DELETE | IN_MODIFY | IN_MOVED_FROM | IN_MOVED_TO | IN_ATTRIB );

while (1){
i=0;
length = read( fd, buffer, EVENT_BUF_LEN ); 
if ( length < 0 ) perror( "reading inotify fd" );
  while ( i < length ) {
    struct inotify_event *event = ( struct inotify_event * ) &buffer[ i ];
    if ( event->len ) {
      if (event->mask & IN_ATTRIB)printf("%s sttributes changed\n",event->name);
      if (event->mask & IN_CREATE)printf("%s created\n",event->name);
      if (event->mask & IN_DELETE)printf("%s deleted\n",event->name);
      if (event->mask & IN_MODIFY)printf("%s modified\n",event->name);
      if (event->mask & IN_MOVED_FROM)printf("%s moved out\n",event->name);
      if (event->mask & IN_MOVED_TO)printf("%s moved in\n",event->name);
    }
    i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len;
  }
}
inotify_rm_watch( fd, watch );
close( fd );
}
```